# Tidying characters in R to the least specific detail based on similarity

Tags: r, string, tidytext

I have a dataframe of drug IDs (NDC_NBR) and their corresponding drug names (BRAND_NM).

I need to collapse/aggregate the drug names to the least specificity as possible per drug.

Here is an example of the data I am working with and the expected outcome:

[image]

```
data <- data.frame(NDC_NBR = c("00002773701","00002775201","00002775205","00002822201","00002822259","00002823301","00002823305","00074024302","00074006702","00074433902"),BRAND_NM = c("INSULIN LISPRO","INSULIN LISPRO JUNIOR KWIKPEN","INSULIN LISPRO JUNIOR KWIKPEN","INSULIN LISPRO KWIKPEN","INSULIN LISPRO KWIKPEN","INSULIN LISPRO PROTAMINE/INSUL","INSULIN LISPRO PROTAMINE/INSUL","HUMIRA","HUMIRA PEDIATRIC CROHNS DISEAS","HUMIRA PEN"), RESULT = c("INSULIN LISPRO","INSULIN LISPRO","INSULIN LISPRO","INSULIN LISPRO","INSULIN LISPRO","INSULIN LISPRO","INSULIN LISPRO","HUMIRA","HUMIRA","HUMIRA"))
```

I wish to collapse these products to the least specific drug names i.e. mutate a new column with the character "INSULIN LISPRO" and "HUMIRA".

"INSULIN LISPRO" is common to the first 7 rows yet "INSULIN LISPRO KWIKPEN" is only common to 2 of the 7. Similarly HUMIRA has no similarity to any of the "INSULIN" rows but is common to all of the last 3 rows.

I have a huge data frame of such products and it's not possible to manually convert each one.

I'd be very grateful if anyone could suggest a solution to such a problem.

Comment: Least specific drug name, you mean in particular row or in whole data frame? Because something like `data$RESULT <- 'INSULIN LISPRO'` isn't what you're looking for right?

Comment: @Adamm thanks for the reply. I'm trying to group drugs to the least specific drug name i.e. "INSULIN LISPRO" is the most frequent term among rows 1-7 therefore that what the result should be for that "group", similarly for "HUMIRA"

Comment: @TheGoat, is there a delimiter between the drugs such as a comma etc?

Comment: how do you know what  the least specific drug name is, for example how do you decide that what you're looking for is "INSULIN LISPRO" and not "INSLUIN"?

Comment: @DS_UNI hi, I guess I am trying to find the least number of common string characters between BRAND_NM i.e. HUMIRA is common to all three HUMIRA products, similarly INSULIN LISPRO is the least common amongst the 7 rows that contain a reference to INSULIN and has no similarity to HUMIRA

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions, each for a different sceanario:

- **Scenario # 1** - you have a list of ideal brand names:

Here's a two-step solution for this scenario:

First, define the short brand names as an alternation pattern `p`:

```
p <- paste0(BRAND_NM_short, collapse = "|")
```

Then use this pattern for `gsub` to match the part in `BRAND_NM` you want to keep and replace `BRAND_NM` with just that matched short brand name:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  mutate(result = gsub(paste0("(", p, ").*"), "\\1", BRAND_NM))
       NDC_NBR                       BRAND_NM         result
1  00002773701                 INSULIN LISPRO INSULIN LISPRO
2  00002775201  INSULIN LISPRO JUNIOR KWIKPEN INSULIN LISPRO
3  00002775205  INSULIN LISPRO JUNIOR KWIKPEN INSULIN LISPRO
4  00002822201         INSULIN LISPRO KWIKPEN INSULIN LISPRO
5  00002822259         INSULIN LISPRO KWIKPEN INSULIN LISPRO
6  00002823301 INSULIN LISPRO PROTAMINE/INSUL INSULIN LISPRO
7  00002823305 INSULIN LISPRO PROTAMINE/INSUL INSULIN LISPRO
8  00074024302                         HUMIRA         HUMIRA
9  00074006702 HUMIRA PEDIATRIC CROHNS DISEAS         HUMIRA
10 00074433902                     HUMIRA PEN         HUMIRA
```

- **Scenario #2**: You don't have a list of the ideal brand names.

Here's a somewhat more complex solution to this problem:

Step 1: Run a `for` loop to detect any repeated words from one row to the next based on a **dynamic** pattern:

```
# initialize vectors/columns:
p1 <- c()
data$repeats <- NA

# for loop to detect repeated words across rows:
library(stringr)
for(i in 2:nrow(data)){
  p1[i-1] <- paste0(unlist(str_split(trimws(data$BRAND_NM[i-1]), "\\s+")), collapse = "|")
  data$repeats[i] <- str_extract_all(data$BRAND_NM[i], p1[i-1])
}
```

Step 2: `mutate` the repeated words to obtain the ideal brand names, assuming that they will maximally contain two words:

```
data %>%
  mutate(result = sapply(repeats, function(x) paste(x[1], x[2], collapse = " ")),
         result = sub("\\sNA", "", result),
         result = ifelse(grepl("NA", result), lead(result), result)) %>%
  select(-repeats)
```

Data:

```
BRAND_NM_short = c("INSULIN LISPRO", "HUMIRA")

data <- data.frame(NDC_NBR = c("00002773701","00002775201","00002775205","00002822201","00002822259","00002823301","00002823305","00074024302","00074006702","00074433902"),
                   BRAND_NM = c("INSULIN LISPRO","INSULIN LISPRO JUNIOR KWIKPEN","INSULIN LISPRO JUNIOR KWIKPEN","INSULIN LISPRO KWIKPEN","INSULIN LISPRO KWIKPEN","INSULIN LISPRO PROTAMINE/INSUL","INSULIN LISPRO PROTAMINE/INSUL","HUMIRA","HUMIRA PEDIATRIC CROHNS DISEAS","HUMIRA PEN"))
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer however I don't have a reference data frame that contains the 'ideal' drug names. I have > 250K rows and it's just not possible to create a master list of 'ideal' drug names.

Comment: Have posted an updated solution. Do let me know if that's better

Answer (score 0):

here's one way to do it, assuming the first word is always part of the name:

```
mydata <- data.frame(NDC_NBR = c("00002773701","00002775201","00002775205","00002822201",
                                 "00002822259","00002823301","00002823305","00074024302",
                                 "00074006702","00074433902"),
                     BRAND_NM = c("INSULIN LISPRO","INSULIN LISPRO JUNIOR KWIKPEN",
                                  "INSULIN LISPRO JUNIOR KWIKPEN","INSULIN LISPRO KWIKPEN",
                                  "INSULIN LISPRO KWIKPEN","INSULIN LISPRO PROTAMINE/INSUL",
                                  "INSULIN LISPRO PROTAMINE/INSUL","HUMIRA",
                                  "HUMIRA PEDIATRIC CROHNS DISEAS","HUMIRA PEN")) 

# add the first word as a main grouping column
mydata["main_group"] <- mydata %>% apply(1, function(x) strsplit(x["BRAND_NM"], " ")[[1]][1])


mydata["RESULT"] <- mydata %>% 
  # per group: get the number of words in common between all rows in group
  group_by(main_group) %>% 
  mutate(intersect_cnt = Reduce(intersect, strsplit(BRAND_NM," ")) %>% length()) %>% 
  # extract the identified words
  apply(1, function(x) paste(strsplit(x["BRAND_NM"], " ")[[1]][1:x["intersect_cnt"]], collapse = " "))
```

output:

```
mydata
#    NDC_NBR                       BRAND_NM main_group         RESULT
# 1  00002773701                 INSULIN LISPRO    INSULIN INSULIN LISPRO
# 2  00002775201  INSULIN LISPRO JUNIOR KWIKPEN    INSULIN INSULIN LISPRO
# 3  00002775205  INSULIN LISPRO JUNIOR KWIKPEN    INSULIN INSULIN LISPRO
# 4  00002822201         INSULIN LISPRO KWIKPEN    INSULIN INSULIN LISPRO
# 5  00002822259         INSULIN LISPRO KWIKPEN    INSULIN INSULIN LISPRO
# 6  00002823301 INSULIN LISPRO PROTAMINE/INSUL    INSULIN INSULIN LISPRO
# 7  00002823305 INSULIN LISPRO PROTAMINE/INSUL    INSULIN INSULIN LISPRO
# 8  00074024302                         HUMIRA     HUMIRA         HUMIRA
# 9  00074006702 HUMIRA PEDIATRIC CROHNS DISEAS     HUMIRA         HUMIRA
# 10 00074433902                     HUMIRA PEN     HUMIRA         HUMIRA
```